# Systick interruption doesn't trigger

Tags: c, stm32

I am experimenting with the `STM32f4` discovery and i tried to use a delay (based on `SYSTICK`) in an `EXTI_IRQ` handler but i figured out that while the `EXTI` handler is triggered the the `systick` handler doesn't trigger , here's my code :

```
extern volatile int del ;
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void) {

  if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line0) != RESET ) {
        /* Do your stuff when PD0 is changed */
         del=1000 ;
         while(del)
       {
       //do something 
       }

       /* Clear interrupt flag */
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
    }
  }
```

And the systick handler :

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  if (del--)
 ;
}
```

So how can i solve this problem .

Comment: Where do you trigger the EXTI? And why would one want to do that - just call the function from the systick interrupt directly. Less perfomance penalty. And your loop in an interrupt handler is quite a bad idea - to say it carefully.

Comment: the extit triggers when a button is pushed

Comment: See [ask], provide a [mcve]! As given you should read more about how to write interrupt handlers and concurrent code on an MCU. And use a debugger, the Cortex-M4 can be debugged quite good.

Comment: Did you initialized it with SysTick_Config?

Comment: Do you not have to explicitly re-enable higher-priority interrupts within your handler, (assuming that SYSTICK is actually a higher priority anyway)?  Also, what Olaf says.  Also poll a free-running timer/counter values instead so that you are not dependent upon another intrrupt.  Also use a real tasker so that you don't have to busy-wait in interrupt-handlers anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames it is not the case of busy waiting here , also a free-running timer is what i am doing here the problem is the timer stops/interrupted when the exti interruption occurs , i know it's a priority problem i tried to lower the exti priority but i still had the same problem

Comment: It doesn't look like polling a free-running timer to me - it looks like polling a variable that is decremented in an interrupt-handler.   By 'poll a free-running timer/counter' I meant read the hardware, not poll some volatile that may, or may not, get decremented in an interrupt-handler.